# Circle radius with Driving Directions in Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom-events, bing-maps

I'm currently developing a web site that are using Bing Maps. I'm using the Bing Maps Version 7. I have created a fully functional driving directions function. Which works like **this:**

> The user rightclicks on the map, where doesn't matter. Then a context menu is brought up, where the user can chose between two alternatives. Which is: **Align Start** and **Align Finish**.

As you might understand those functions are creating a way-point on the locations of where the user right-clicked. Also a radius circle is aligned on respective way-point. Both start and finish way-points are **dragable** / **movable**, which means that the user can move the way-points around. The problem is that when the user moves one of the way-points the radius circle isn't moving also, which not is weird because I have not created a function for that yet. I don't think that is hard to do, but I don't know how to get the new position of the moved way-point. I'm posting my code. So I do really need some help with making this **"RadiusCircleMove"**.

*Here is my Javascript Code:*

```
var map = null;
var directionsManager;
var directionsErrorEventObj;
var directionsUpdatedEventObj;
var startPosition;
var checkpointPosition;
var finishPosition;
var popuplat;
var popuplon;
var waypointType;
var startcircle;
var checkpointcircle;
var finishcircle;
var startcirclelat;
var startcirclelon;
var checkpointcirclelat;
var checkpointcirclelon;
var finishcirclelat;
var finishcirclelon;

$(document).ready(function () {
    //this one line will disable the right mouse click menu
    $(document)[0].oncontextmenu = function () { return false; }
    GetMap();
});

function GetMap() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), { credentials: "Enter Bing Key Here", zoom: 4, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, -100) });
    Microsoft.Maps.registerModule("BMv7.AdvancedShapes", "BMv7.AdvancedShapes.min.js");
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("BMv7.AdvancedShapes");
    //map.AttachEvent("onclick", ShowPopupMenu);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', RemovePopupMenu);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'rightclick', ShowPopupMenu);
}

function ShowPopupMenu(e) {
    var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    popuplat = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point).latitude
    popuplon = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point).longitude
    var menu = document.getElementById('popupmenu');
    menu.style.display = 'block'; //Showing the menu
    menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px"; //Positioning the menu
    menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
}

function RemovePopupMenu() {
    document.getElementById("popupmenu").style.display = 'none';
}

function createDirectionsManager() {
    var displayMessage;
    if (!directionsManager) {
        directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
        //displayMessage = 'Directions Module loaded\n';
        //displayMessage += 'Directions Manager loaded';
    }
    //alert(displayMessage);
    directionsManager.resetDirections();
    directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function () {} );
}

function createDrivingRoute() {

        if (!directionsManager) { createDirectionsManager(); }

        directionsManager.resetDirections();

        // Set Route Mode to driving

            directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });

            if (waypointType == "start") {
                addDefaultPushpin();
                startPosition = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(popuplat, popuplon) });
                startcirclelat = popuplat;
                startcirclelon = popuplon;
            }

            if (waypointType == "checkpoint") {
                addDefaultPushpin();
                checkpointPosition = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(popuplat, popuplon) });
                checkpointcirclelat = popuplat;
                checkpointcirclelon = popuplon;
            }

            if (waypointType == "finish") {
                finishPosition = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(popuplat, popuplon) });
                finishcirclelat = popuplat;
                finishcirclelon = popuplon;
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(startPosition);
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(checkpointPosition);
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(finishPosition);
                directionsManager.calculateDirections();
                deletePushpin();
                CreateStartCircle();
                CreateCheckpointCircle();
                CreateFinishCircle();
            }
            // Set the element in which the itinerary will be rendered

            directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('directionsItinerary') });

            //alert('Calculating directions...');


}

function createDirections() {
    if (!directionsManager) {
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: createDrivingRoute });
    }
    else {
        createDrivingRoute();
    }
}

function AddStartPosition() {
    waypointType = "start";
    createDirections();
    RemovePopupMenu();
}

function AddCheckpointPosition() {
    waypointType = "checkpoint";
    createDirections();
    RemovePopupMenu();
}

function AddFinishPosition() {
    waypointType = "finish";
    createDirections();
    RemovePopupMenu();
}
    function addDefaultPushpin() {
        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(popuplat, popuplon));
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
    }

    function deletePushpin() {
        for (var i = map.entities.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var pushpin = map.entities.get(i);
            if (pushpin instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin) {
                map.entities.removeAt(i);
            };
        }
    }
    function CreateStartCircle() {
        startcircle = DecStartCircle();
        map.entities.push(startcircle);
    }
    function CreateCheckpointCircle() {
        checkpointcircle = DecCheckpointCircle();
        map.entities.push(checkpointcircle);
    }
    function CreateFinishCircle() {
        finishcircle = DecFinishCircle();
        map.entities.push(finishcircle);
    }

      /***** Start Circle ****/
    function DecStartCircle() {
        var polygonOptions = {
            fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 0, 0, 255),
            strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 255, 0, 0)
        };
        return new BMv7.AdvanceShapes.Circle(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(startcirclelat, startcirclelon), 80000, polygonOptions);
    }

    /***** Checkpoint Circle ****/
    function DecCheckpointCircle() {
        var polygonOptions = {
            fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 0, 0, 255),
            strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 255, 0, 0)
        };
        return new BMv7.AdvanceShapes.Circle(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(checkpointcirclelat, checkpointcirclelon), 80000, polygonOptions);
    }

    /***** Finish Circle ****/
    function DecFinishCircle() {
        var polygonOptions = {
            fillColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 0, 0, 255),
            strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 255, 0, 0)
        };
        return new BMv7.AdvanceShapes.Circle(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(finishcirclelat, finishcirclelon), 80000, polygonOptions);
    }
```

Comment: `$(document)[0].oncontextmenu = function () { return false; }` may possibly qualify for the dumbest line of code ever written.  Please use `document.oncontextmenu` or `$(document).on("contextmenu")`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to actually implement your DirectionsUpdated event. Your code contains the following empty function:

```
directionsUpdatedEventObj = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function () {} );
```

You shouldn't be doing anything with the map until the directions have completed loading. Once they have loaded, then you can do the following:

1. Clear all map entities `map.entities.clear();` which removes all previous polylines and polygons
2. Then reset directions: `directionsManager.resetDirections();` to clear the current     directions (otherwise you'll see waypoints appended).
3. Then [get all of the waypoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx) from the directions module   `directionsManager.getAllWaypoints();`
4. Now plot your three circles.

Your problem is one of timing and correct sequencing.